# React router has ErrorBoundary or errorElement prop on your route

Tags: react-router

this is my app.js

```
import {createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider} from "react-router-dom";
import RootLayout from "./pages/Root";
import HomePage from "./pages/Home";
import MatchingPage from "./pages/Matching";
import RankingListPage from "./pages/RankingList";
import ShoppingPage from "./pages/Shopping";
import PersonalCenterPage from "./pages/PersonalCenter";
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {path:'/',element:<RootLayout/>
        ,children:[
            {path:'/',element:<HomePage/>},
            {path:'/matching',element:<MatchingPage/>},
            {path:'/rankinglist',element:<RankingListPage/>},
            {path:'/shopping',element:<ShoppingPage/>},
            {path:'/personalcenter',element:<PersonalCenterPage/>},
        ]
    },

]);

function App() {
    return <RouterProvider router={router}/>
}
export default App;
```

and this is my Root.js:

```
import {Outlet} from 'react-router-dom'
import MainNavigation from "../components/MainNavigation";

function RootLayout(){
    return (
        <>
            <MainNavigation/>
            <h1>Layout</h1>
            <Outlet/>
        </>
    );
}

export default RootLayout;
```

and then the Home.js,Mathing.js,PersonalCenter.js,Shopping.js,RankingList.js are the same at most instead of the title name of different pages, the tempelete like this(make Home.js as a example):

```
function  HomePage(){
    return(

            <h1>My Home Page</h1>

    )
}
export default HomePage;
```

AND the MainNavigation.js which is in Root.js is as follows:

```
import {Outlet} from 'react-router-dom'
import MainNavigation from "../components/MainNavigation";

function RootLayout(){
    return (
        <>
            <MainNavigation/>
            <h1>Layout</h1>
            <Outlet/>
        </>
    );
}

export default RootLayout;
```

---

BUT  After local depolyment(I use creat-react-app), it has error in page[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRir7.png)

I use react 18, react router 6

I have try to Comment out the router code change to : "return <h1>hello</h1> "in App.js and it works , but if I  use "return <RouterProvider router={router}/> "instead, it just appears error like img above.

Comment: The only issue I see in the code is that you are rendering `HomePage` as the root layout route when you likely meant to render `RootLayout`, but I don't believe this would cause the 404 error you are getting from the server. *What* in your routing code is requesting something from a server? Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] and debugging details.

Comment: Ohh, sorry, my uploaded code is wrong, the previous code is RootLayout

Comment: and this are just some static pages in front-end, I haven't written requests for back-end, that is strange.

Comment: Yeah, that was the only issue in the code that I could see. Try to create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we can inspect live.

Comment: Ohhh , thanks, I found where has error, I just write the wrong path name, but I haven't put this code above, just the base path name , but my path names in router haven't contained the base path name